# Yii, Is possible to render another information from another controller/action?

Tags: php, yii

well, just to avoid too much coding, i was wondering if there could be a way to call a controller/action just to show information, something like iframe.

i've create another layout column that has 3 columns and will render most of the time the same information, and it will change if it is needed, i already made a code in the layout to do the work i want it to do, but just for curiousity, is possible to render another controller?

this is my column/layout:

```
<?php
$this->beginContent('//layouts/main');

if(isset($_GET['user']))
    $user = Users::model()->findByPk($_GET['user'])->attributes;

else
    $user = Users::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->getId())->attributes;
?>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="well well-success text-center">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->renderImg($user['img_path']);?>" alt="User" class="img-rounded"  width="90%"    height="auto">
    </div>  
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2><?php echo $user['nombre']; ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php echo $user['bio']; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div id="content" class="col-md-6">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div><!-- content -->

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="user">
            <div class="well text-center">
                <a href="#a">
                    <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/images/1D3.jpg" class="img-rounded"  width="90%"   height="auto">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-info panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Anuncio del Restaurante
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body text-justu">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                    adipisicing elit. Enim pariatur aliquid a nemo soluta dignissimos
                    minus accusamus porro natus autem cum error odio exercitationem
                    quidem veritatis itaque quas, laudantium ipsam!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
        $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.CPortlet', array(
            'title'=>'Operations',
        ));
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
            'items'=>$this->menu,
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'operations'),
        ));
        $this->endWidget();
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

it's a work in progress, i want to "this code" in my first div.col-md-3, as you can see i already made the code in there..

the controller(different) i wish to call would have this action:

```
public function actionPreview($id)
    {
        $model = $this->checkUser($id);

        $this->renderPartial('preview', array(
            'model'=>$model
        ));
    }
```

and the view of this action would have this code:

```
<div class="well well-success text-center">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->renderImg($model->img_path);?>" alt="User" class="img-rounded"  width="90%" height="auto">
</div>  
<div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2><?php echo $model->nombre; ?></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <?php echo $model->bio; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

just like in the first div located in the layout.

i'm just making this question for curiousity, i'm not in rush and i just want to practice more coding, if there is a way to do this maybe other people would find this really useful

Comment: @user1954544 i use it to keep information track, this is a work in progress, later i will change the name

Comment: if you want more practice read about patterns, answer for your question is simple in one word 'layouts' read about it and you will get an answer

Comment: if you found in my answer helpful information, please mark as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Re-read this one http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller

Define in controller another action

```
class PostController extends CController
{
    public function actions()
    {
        return array(
            'edit'=>'application.controllers.post.UpdateAction',
        );
    }
}
```

After that yo can call it in your action like (AFAIK)

```
$this->edit();
```

So you should do standalone action to get it rendered. Also read about `renderPartial()` and `widgets` that can also help you. Another way to go is create a component that will render you need, but it will looks like `Yii::app()->myComponent->getSomeHtml()`.

So there are a lots of stuff you can use to do you want.

Also you can do on layout that will have three `$content` vars. Through your abstractController you can create any data in each one. Base thing that in abstract controller will be loaded needed for you layout, in main controller class you will select actions that will be rendered in each column (here you can use any solutions I showed earlier) and you will get ANY customized count of columns...

**ADDED**

```
class ControllerAbstract extends CController
{
    public $layout = 'default';

    public function setLayout($sLayout)
    {
        $this->layout = $sLayout;

        return $this;
    }
}

class Controller extends ControllerAbstract
{

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->setLayout('column_three');
        // or without method
        // $this->layout = 'column_three';

        $aData = array(
            'column1' => $this->getHtmlColumn(1),
            'column2' => $this->getHtmlColumn(2),
            'column3' => $this->getHtmlColumn(3),
        );

        $this->render('index', $aData);
    }

    public function getHtmlColumn($iType)
    {
        // here i won't show how call standalone action - read yii manual

        $sHtml = '';

        switch ($iType) {
            case 1:
                // here call some functions to get html
                $sHtml = '1';
                break;
            case 2:
                // here call some functions to get html
                $sHtml = '2';
                break;
            case 3:
                // here call some functions to get html
                $sHtml = '3';
                break;

            default:
                $sHtml = 'incorrect input, no data';
                break;
        }

        return $sHtml;
    }
}
```

Also read this (native by yii)
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/28/how-to-implement-multiple-page-layouts-in-an-application/

Comment: i though on do $content for each div, but i thought it would just render the same action three times, i will start looking how to do so

Comment: i would like to have an example of $content for each div, could you show me one if you have some of it?

Comment: added base description, you should change it what ever you need, also you can re-declair render method to change it behaviour, main thing - change layout - assing for this layout needed vars. you can add\edit it even before render (in abstract controller class), simple example is 'user is banned on the server is doing through abstract controller, that will decide can user see the page or not'